# JavaScript array iterators

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I am doing this exercise and I don't understand why it doesn't work. Anyone willing to help?

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

const storyWords = story.split(' ');

console.log(storyWords.lenght);


const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word=>{
  if (word === unnecessaryWords){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(betterWords);
```

The first console.log should return the lenght but it returns undefined.
In the second console.log nothing has been filtered.
what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Its `.length` !

Comment: Be aware that `.split(' ')` will make your approach miss words followed by something like `,`, `.`, `:` etc. Example: `Last weekend, literally, I took ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

const storyWords = story.split(' ');

console.log(storyWords.length); // length spelling mistake


const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word=>{
  if (unnecessaryWords.includes(word)){ // check words in the array like that
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(betterWords);
```

Comment: `return !unnecessaryWords.includes(word)`

Comment: i understand your pov.... but i have shown what are the mistakes in code...

Comment: @mplungjan `.filter(word=>!unnecessaryWords.includes(word))`

Comment: @connexo even better :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for no first `console.log` is because there is typo on `length` property. You are using `lenght` which is invalid.

The reason for no second `console.log` is because there is a array of `unnecessaryWords` so you need to use `indexOf()` (or `includes()`) to check if the words exist in that array or not:

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually'];

const storyWords = story.split(' ');

console.log(storyWords.length);


const betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => {
  return unnecessaryWords.indexOf(word) === -1;
});

console.log(betterWords);
```

Answer (score -2):

Kindly try this below:

It is storyWords.length not lenght;

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';


var storyWords = story.split(' ');

console.log(storyWords.length) // not lenght;


function betterWords(storyWords) {
  foreach(var word in storyWords) {
    if (word === unnecessaryWords) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(betterWords(story));
```

Comment: this is not valid JS `foreach(var word in storyWords) {`

Comment: You are missing unnecessaryWords and you cannot compare a string to an array. Please see other answers on this page